# How to copy a list of files in perl from one directory to another

Tags: file, grep, perl, copy

In UNIX get the files from `DIRECTORY_PATH` based on file format and last modified date and move the file to `ARCHIVE_DIRECTORY`

For that used the below piece of code

```
DIRECTORY_PATH=/apps/data/central_archive/
NO_OF_DAYS_ARCHIVE=10
FILE_FORMAT=txt
EXEC_CMD=mv
ARCHIVE_DIRECTORY=/apps/data/archive/

res=`find $DIRECTORY_PATH -mtime $NO_OF_DAYS_ARCHIVE -name "*$FILE_FORMAT*" -type f|grep "$DIRECTORY_PATH[^/]*$" | grep -v '/rf/'`
```

Here how do implement the same logic in Perl?

Comment: Why do you want to do this in Perl?

Answer (score 1):

One way, using [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Copy;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir = 'src/';
my $arch_dir = 'archive/';
my $days = 10;
my $type = '*.txt';

if (! -d $arch_dir){
    mkdir $arch_dir or die $!;
}

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                            ->name($type)
                            ->mtime('> ' . (time() - $days*24*60*60))
                            ->in($dir);

for (@files){
    move $_, $arch_dir or die $!;
    print "moved $_ to $arch_dir/\n";
}
```